# FxCop rule to detect swallowed exceptions

Tags: code-analysis, fxcop, static-code-analysis

is there a FxCop rule to find swallowed exceptions?

I have found this article http://mystuffisallhere.com/blog/post/2006/01/02/An-FxCop-rule-to-detect-swallowed-exceptions.aspx but I can not find the code or dll which does the job.

thanks
almir

Comment: Perhaps you should attempt to write the rule yourself. If you get stuck, ask a question here so that the community can help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

CA1031 [1] should "catch" the worse offenders, i.e. the "catch-all"

Gendarme [2] has a similar rule [3] and full source code is available if you wish to extend it into detecting every cases where exceptions are swallowed.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182137%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

[2] disclosure: I'm Gendarme maintainer

[3] https://github.com/spouliot/gendarme/wiki/Gendarme.Rules.Exceptions.DoNotSwallowErrorsCatchingNonSpecificExceptionsRule%282.10%29